Realtime cuboid vs cylinder classification of a 2D mask / object from a 3D scene?
Most realtime SOTA segmentation/detection model can reliably segment an object from a 2D input, and I can get the contours/polylines describing its edges in realtime. By realtime, I'll consider anything in the ~10ms range on a NVIDIA A100.
However, the contours of a cube projected on a 2D input (any IRL camera with perspective projection) are not a square. I know that there are some polyline matching algorithms but I don't have enough contours from all possible perspectives to train a classifier (or possibly fine-tune an existing CV model that has spatial awareness). I could in theory use 3d rendering software to generate a ton of instances in the worst case. I'm considering both supervised and non supervised approaches. For example, there's approxPolyDP in OpenCV, but it wouldn't really work.
Since the objects in questions are household items, 3D reconstruction models like https://one-2-3-45.github.io/ do work in practice (and then I can do trivial operations to classify) but they are quite slow - i.e. >20 seconds.

Are there any datasets, pretrained models or unsupervised linear algebraic approaches that would map a 2D object mask and/or RGB object (viewed from an arbitrary perspective) to a real number [0, 1] representing how close it is to a cylinder vs a cuboid?

Is querying OpenAI CLIP with the image and some 'round' / 'cuboid' word embedding and doing cosine similarity a realistic solution?

I'm aware that this is an ambiguous problem in some cases (ex. a cylinder is a rectangle in some orientations). How much should I focus on the RGB / lighting of the object, assuming I care a lot about the precision?


